# How can I copy a Playlist from one iTunes library to another?

Tags: macos, itunes, windows, playlist

I have one iTunes instance (v10.6.0.40) a Windows 7 PC.  I'm having problems copying playlists from there to my Macbook Air's iTunes instance.  Here's what I do:

1. On the Win7 machine, I right click the Playlist, choose Export, export it as a .m3u8 file, and save it in my Dropbox.
2. On the MBA, I grab the new playlist from the Dropbox, and drop it into the Mac's iTunes library.

After that, instead of a list of songs from they Playlist, I just get this:

[image: A blank playlist, I guess?]

Which I guess means that the newly imported playlist is blank.

How can I (successfully) copy playlists between two computers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the File menu, In the Library expanding list, you will find "Export Playlist".

On the receiving machine you would use "Import Playlist" found in the same menu.

Seems like you have the right procedure (although I do not know for sure that drag and drop will work with the playlist...) but have you tried to export a .txt file - that's what I get when I export a playlist. If you have the option could you export it as txt, verify that the file contains a list of songs, then verify that it also contains a list of songs when you get it back from dropbox? You should at least be able to isolate where the list disappears.

Comment: Using "Import Playlist" on the Mac doesn't work either - same result.

Comment: Any luck on looking at the content of the exported file? On Windows if you can export as .txt it would be fine to open it in notepad.

Comment: Exporting as .txt and then Importing worked!

Comment: I've done the export/import option before. I can add to that it only works if you first import the actual tracks, they're separate. That said, something has changed - import/export no longer show up, which is why I'm here.